# How to assign a value to a range of indices in rust?

Tags: python, rust, primes

I am looking for a replacement for this python code in rust:

```
full_array[test:max:index] = False
```

I am working on converting a python prime sieve I made to rust. I am new to the language and can't find a suitable solution without introducing looping.

in python my sieve can filter 10B values in under a minute, so I am looking to get similar performant code. Which loops won't accommodate.

I don't even know where to start, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: That statement creates a loop.  You just don't see it, because it's in C inside the interpreter.  In Rust, you're compiling directly to machine language, so you need to be more explicit.

Comment: So I just do loops?

Comment: This idiom is nothing but syntactic sugar for the for loop that the interpreter will be executing. Nothing to be gained by this but see the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the same value to all elements in a slice by using [`.fill()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.fill):

```
let mut full_array = vec![true, false, true, true, false, true];
full_array[0..3].fill(false);
println!("{:?}", full_array);
```

```
[false, false, false, true, false, true]
```

The slicing syntax in Python is `[start:stop:step]`, so if your `index` implies a non-one step size, you'd have to resort to iterators since the method above only works on contiguous elements:

```
let mut full_array = vec![true, false, true, true, false, true];
full_array.iter_mut().step_by(3).for_each(|i| *i = false);
println!("{:?}", full_array);
```

```
[false, false, true, false, false, true]
```